# Is there a way to programmatically import ICS into Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, gcal

I don't see any obvious way to import ICS files into Google Calendar from the API docs here:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/developers_guide_protocol.html

And I'd greatly prefer not to have to parse them myself just to send the appointments into GCal.  I'm looking for a programmatic solution, not something like import plugins for Thunderbird, Outlook, etc.  Third party APIs to do the ICS parsing are acceptable, in any language.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any progress on this question? Is it really impossible to import a ics into Google Calendar without parsing it before?

Comment: The top two answers below seem plausible, but I was not able to test them and get them working.  And now I no longer have an urgent need for the functionality.  If either the C# or the Ruby solution below work, let me know!

Comment: Note that the lack of API support for directly importing ICS files is the topic of this entry in google's bug tracking system: [Issue 210 - apps-api-issues - Ability to import Standard iCalendar (.ics) file](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=210)

Answer (score 6):

I have created a simple open source .net utility to do just that, available at http://gcalicsimporter.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Looks good, although I couldn't get it running on Mono on OS X.

Comment: I'm looking for Java example, but .NET solution should be OK for me too.

Comment: @JoeShaw what problem did you run in to with gcalicsimporter on mono?

Comment: @nealmcb Sorry, I don't remember, it was 4.5 years ago.

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to parse an ICS just to import it into Google Calendar, it is capable of importing them directly...  From the end-user's web view, it's as easy as clicking Import Calendar.  From the API, I would look at the [Adding New Subscriptions](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/developers_guide_protocol.html#AddingSubscriptions) section.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because I don't want to subscribe to a web-based calendar.  The data I want to push in isn't available on the web.  I want to basically upload a file and have Google calendar become the canonical store for it.

Comment: @Grank not an answer for the OP, still what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

For my iCal2GCal app I'm using the [Googlecalendar Ruby Gem](http://googlecalendar.rubyforge.org/) to both parse .ics files and then add the events inside to a Googlecalendar. It might give you some ideas on how to go about it. You can check out the full [source code](http://github.com/relix/iCal2GCal/blob/0a233ad506ecb55ed924bd86fca1621c2cdbd616/ical2gcal.rb).

Comment: Unfortunately the googlecalendar rubygem doesn't seem to work with Google Apps accounts, so I can't test this.