# Can't add .ical file by url to Google, but the importing works on Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to give a client url, to add his and everyone elses event in a scheduled site.

The site works with fullcalendar.io, the client gets his url from the site.
Example URL:
`http://scheduleme.catom.com/Ical/Ical.ashx?GUID=&ID=6`

I Can't add .ical file by url to Google calander, but the importing works on Outlook

The .ashx looks like:

```
public class Ical : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int I_ID = 0;
        int user = 0;
        string filename = "";
        //string username = "";
        string UD_GUID = context.Request.QueryString["GUID"];
        if (Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["ID"], out I_ID))
        {
            I_ID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        }

        if (Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["user"], out user))
        {
            user = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["user"]);
        }
        List<IcalClass> events = new List<IcalClass>();

        if (user == 1)
        {
            events.FillData(UD_GUID,I_ID);
            filename = "my_orders_" + (events.Count > 0 ? events.First().I_Title : "");
        }
        else
        {
            events.FillData(I_ID);
            filename = "all_orders_" + (events.Count > 0 ? events.First().I_Title : "");
        }


        //username = events.First().UD_UserName;

        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();

        r.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        r.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        r.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN");
        r.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
        r.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");
        r.AppendLine("X-WR-CALNAME:" + filename);

        foreach (IcalClass item in events)
        {
            r.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            DateTime start = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(item.OD_StartDate);
            DateTime end = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(item.OD_EndDate);

            r.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + start.Year + start.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + start.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "T" + start.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + start.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + start.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "Z");
            r.AppendLine("DTEND:" + end.Year + end.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + end.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "T" + end.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + end.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + end.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "Z");
            string row = "SUMMARY:" + item.I_Title + "[" + item.UD_UserName + " " + item.OT_Title;
            if (item.UD_UserNameService.Length > 0)
            {
                row += "-" + item.UD_UserNameService + "]";
            }
            else
            {
                row += "]";
            }
            r.AppendLine(row);
            r.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        }

        r.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/calendar; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".ics");
        context.Response.Write(r.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135302/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-import-ics-into-google-calendar

Comment: Cant find answer in this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , after some read i figure out that is a common problem

Look on https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en&ref_topic=1672445
check out the note:
"Note: It may take up to 8 hours for changes in ICS feeds to reflect in your Google Calendar."

But the problem will come back after reloading.

Is there any way to work around this problem ?